# Meaning of voting to yes/no questions in users' perspective

Tags: discussion, voting, psychology

In past, several times I saw that, when a meta question is asked in yes/no question format, those whose answers are "yes" up-vote the question, and those whose answers are "no" down-vote the question. When the question is not asked in yes/no format, people rather vote it more likely by its quality.

For example, if you ask your question in the following yes/no question form
`Should every answer contain a reference from an outside source?`
if people oppose the idea, they down-vote the question.

But, if you ask the question like
`What do you think about the necessity of outside references in answers?`
The trend of the up/down votes change dramatically.

What do you think about this psychological phenomenon? Do you think that all users truely understand the purpose of voting (especially the purpose of down-voting)? Some people behave like they are on Facebook, and they become very happy with the "dislike" button they find here, which is missing in there. I know, there are tool-tips giving information when you however your mouse on the up and down vote buttons. But, maybe we should display a larger and more vivid panel which include more information about the purpose of voting, at least for new users.

What else could be done to solve this problem of different voting for same two questions which have the same meaning but written with different words?

Comment: "What else could be done to solve this problem"... I don't really see a problem to be honest. From time to time an introduction is required for the OP of a question (OMG, TEH DOWNVOTEZ!!! THEY HAPPEN WHY??) but that's about it.

Comment: I don't really see a problem at all. People down vote because *they feel like down voting*. It's usually not difficult to imagine why that could be.

Comment: I guess people learn how to phrase their posts so as not to be downvoted into oblivion. This takes a little Meta experience but I guess there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the distinction is that neat.

For example, to the question *"Should every answer contain a reference from an outside source?"* I'd upvote if:

- I agree with the proposal
- I like how the question is posed
- I like the fact that someone proposed it in the first place
- I am not sure with the proposal but it makes a good point that wasn't addressed before
- or all of these together. :)

I'd downvote in case the opposite is true (I disagree, the question is badly formatted, it doesn't treat the issue properly or in depth, etc.).

Voting on Meta is different but on MSO is even more different. Here you have both the Meta rating logic but also the Main site one. You vote because you agree but also because something is wrong, although it's true that this might happen in Child Metas as well.

Like they told you in the comments, there isn't really a problem... You can "avoid" huge downvote bombarding by tweaking your wording. This can be a disadvantage for new users, but as you gain some experience, you can use it to your own advantage.

Consider that I've seen bad proposals still be upvoted because they were greatly treated by the OP and not just "PLEEZ FIX EET".